# Branch - Fetch / Pull from remote using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit v 1.8.9.0 as my client.

I have a git repository with currently has 2 branches. The HEAD branch and also the 1.0.0-Enhancements branch.

[image]

The 1.0.0-Enhancements branch is not up to date in my local repository. So when I look at the commit history of this branch on my local using TortoiseGit it does not show the commits on this branch that I can see on the remote in GitWeb.

Here are two screenshots which illustrate that my local copy of the 1.0.0-Enhancements branch is missing commits.

**-->History on my local using TortoiseGit**
[image]

**-->History of remote on GitWeb**
[image]

My ultimate goal is to merge the 1.0.0-Enhancements branch into the HEAD branch however before I do this I believe that the 1.0.0-Enhancements branch should be up to date on my local.

I have been trying for a couple of hours now to try and find a way to fetch 1.0.0-Enhancements commit from the remote to my local but can't find a way. This is what I tried ...

1. Make tortoise Git Switch to 1.0.0-Enhancements branch.
   [image]
2. Use tortoiseGit to fetch from the remote branch.
   [image]

But after doing this when I look at the history of my 1.0.0-Enhancements branch the missing commits are still missing. Can someone help me with how I might fix this?

**--Update for answer byt @CupCake--**

TortoiseGit also comes with a bash prompt. I tried both your suggestions using the command line but they did not work. Here are the results.

[image]
[image]

But I did seem to make some progress with trying a git pull from the TortoiseGit UI.
[image]

Which seemed to work except it came back with an error:

> git.exe pull -v --progress       "origin" 1.0.0-ENHANCEMENTS
>
> From ssh://upredmine/cvs/repo/codeRepository/git/repo04/EPOS/EPOSWeb
>   * branch            1.0.0-ENHANCEMENTS -> FETCH_HEAD Updating 67b6537..ee38b20 
>   error: The following untracked working tree files
>   would be overwritten by merge:
>   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
>   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
>   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.prefs
>   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core.prefs
>
> .metadata/version.ini Please move or remove them before you can merge.
>   Aborting
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (1094 ms @ 16/07/2014 3:32:47
>   PM)

Can you give me some feedback on this. Do I need to force an update or synch?

Comment: `HEAD` **is not actually a branch in your remote repo**, it's a symbolic reference that points to the default branch in the remote, which is usually `master`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: @Cupcake ah.. thanks for pointing that out. It will help me with my terminology in the future.

Comment: @Cupcake I've read that link. So are you saying that if I did a pull instead of a fetch the remote commits would be pulled down to my local. Why would a fetch not work?

Comment: [The answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/456814) is simple: "*In the simplest terms, 'git pull' does a 'git fetch' followed by a 'git merge'.*".

Comment: Did you try looking up how to merge or pull using TortoiseGit?

Comment: Actually sorry. I forgot to add something about the TortoiseGit pull to my answer. Let me add it.

Comment: Also, you know you can copy and paste from your terminal, right? You might have to modify the preferences, but you can select to highlight and right-click to copy. It's easier to read than screenshots.

Comment: The error you get when trying the pull: "*The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:*" It means you have a dirty working copy with modified or untracked files. You either need to stash them or commit them before you do the pull/merge. In general, you never want to pull or merge into a dirty working copy.

Comment: ok. So I got rid of the untracked files and it worked. The enhancements branch is no up to date! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem that you're having is that you're only fetching your enhancements branch into your local repo, but you're not actually merging the remote-tracking branch `origin/1.0.0-Enhancements` into your local `1.0.0-Enhancements` branch.

Basically, you're branches are set up like this (let X represent your enhancements branch):

[image: Branches]

As you see in the diagram above, there are 3 branches involved:

1. The local version of X.
2. The remote version of X.
3. A *local* remote-tracking branch `origin/X`, which keeps track of where the remote version of X is.

By using `git fetch`, you update the local remote-tracking branch `origin/1.0.0-Enhancements` in your local repo...but that's a separate branch from your local `1.0.0-Enhancements` branch.

So, what you want to do is either:

1. `git pull`, or
2. `git merge` the remote-tracking branch.

Note that `git pull` is really just a combination of `git fetch` followed by `git merge` of the branch that you just fetched.

### Option 1: Merge

Since you've already fetched, you just need to merge `origin/1.0.0-Enhancements` into your local `1.0.0-Enhancements` branch. I don't know how you do this in TortoiseGit (I stopped using that years ago), but if you want to do it from the command line, you simply do

```
git checkout 1.0.0-Enhancements
git merge origin/1.0.0-Enhancements
```

### Option 2: Pull

In the future, in cases where you didn't fetch first, you can execute a pull into your local branch from the remote branch instead. Again, I don't know how to do this in TortoiseGit anymore, but if you wanted to do it from the command line, you simply do

```
git checkout 1.0.0-Enhancements
git pull origin 1.0.0-Enhancements
```

### Note on the HEAD symbolic reference

So the symbolic reference `origin/HEAD` **is not a branch**. It's simply a special reference that points to the default branch in the (bare) remote repo...the same branch that gets checked out by default by any clones of that repo.

In a **non-bare** repo, `HEAD` is still a symbolic reference, but instead of pointing to a default branch, it instead points to either the currently checked out branch, or the currently checked out commit, if you're not currently on the tip of a branch (e.g. "detached HEAD" state).

### Documentation

- [git-pull(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)
- [git-fetch(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html)
- [git-merge(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I did not know local remote-tracking branch. I tried both of your suggestions and they did not work. I've updated my post to show the output

Comment: sorry i just sent them through now

Comment: Thank you. Even though we took a few goes to get this right your explanation in particular of the remote tracking branch was very interesting and knowledge I didn't have. Appreciate your time on this.

Comment: You're welcome `;)`. If you have time to read it, I also recommend that you check out the FREE [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), which is available online and also in Kindle, iPad, and PDF versions, especially chapters 1-3, 6-6.5. It's how I went from Git n00b to [Git Master](http://stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake)! `:D`